# Wrong authenticationDatabase when seeding MongoDB with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

I have a Laravel app that uses MongoDB.
I'm unfamiliar with Laravel or PHP in general, but I just poke around stuff and follow the logs. The project owner has set-up some basic config and the `.env`, but in some cases devs have to modify those themselves.

I was trying to seed the database when I encountered an `Authentication failed` error. After reading this GitHub issue:

[Authentication Error · Issue #21 · jenssegers/laravel-mongodb · GitHub](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/21)

I tried changing around stuff and here's the part from my `config/database.php`

```php
'mongodb' => [
            'driver' => 'mongodb',
            'dsn' => env('MONGO_DSN'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'port' => env('MONGO_PORT'),
            'database' => env('MONGO_DATABASE'), // value: "definitely_exists_but_not_admin"
            'options' => [
                'database' => 'admin',
                'db' => 'admin'
            ]
        ],
```

When I run it again, it refuses to use `admin` as authentication database. here's what the Mongo log says (note the value of `attr.authenticationDatabase`):

```json
{
  "t":{
    "$date":"2021-10-08T08:54:33.091+00:00"
  },
  "s":"I",
  "c":"ACCESS",
  "id":20249,
  "ctx":"conn4",
  "msg":"Authentication failed",
  "attr":{
    "mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-1",
    "speculative":false,
    "principalName":"root",
    "authenticationDatabase":"definitely_exists_but_not_admin",
    "remote":"****",
    "extraInfo":{
      
    },
    "error":"UserNotFound: Could not find user \"root\" for db \"definitely_exists_but_not_admin\""
  }
}
```

Is there something I should change?

Answer (score 1):

The [mongo sample](https://www.mongodb.com/compatibility/mongodb-laravel-intergration) says that it is possible to use uri

```
'connections' => [
  mongodb' => [
    'driver' => 'mongodb',
    'dsn' => env('DB_URI', 'mongodb+srv://username:password@127.0.0.1/myappdb?retryWrites=true&w=majority'),
    'database' => 'myappdb',
],
```

If so then you might try adding a parameter for `authenticationDatabase` to use like

```
mongodb+srv://username:password@127.0.0.1/myappdb?retryWrites=true&w=majority&authSource=admin
```

`authSource=admin` tells to use admin collection for `authenticationDatabase`. Or maybe `authSource=admin` would go through in options. (Do not have laravel installed to test but authSource in uri works for me)